# same div codes but does not work correctly

Tags: php, mysql, fonts, html-lists

I am editing [THIS PAGE](http://www.xclo.mobi/xclo2/)

If you take a look you will see the problem that I am having.

**The bottom 2 links do not match the top 3.**

here is the code:

```
 <?PHP 
include_once('include/connection.php'); 
include_once('include/article.php');

$category = new category;
$articles = $category->fetch_all();


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Xclo.mobi</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="other.css" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="homescreen.png" />
<link href="startup.png" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />


<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-34172259-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xclo.co.uk']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>


<div id="content">
<ul class="pageitem">
<li class="button"><input name="Submit" value="Food" onclick="window.location='food.html' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
<ul class="pageitem">
<li class="button"><input name="Submit" value="Make A Change" onclick="window.location='change.html' " type="submit" /></li></ul>
<ul class="pageitem">
<li class="button"><input name="Submit" value="Finance" onclick="window.location='insurance.html' " type="submit" /></li></ul>

<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button">    
<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;"/>
</li></ul>
          </a> <?php } ?>

</div>
<br><center>
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=GB&ID=V20070822%2FGB%2Fxclo-21%2F8002%2Fc2cd2f40-ca29-49bc-add9-6cf16307e855"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=GB&ID=V20070822%2FGB%2Fxclo-21%2F8002%2Fc2cd2f40-ca29-49bc-add9-6cf16307e855&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.co.uk Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT></center>

<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

the top 3 are manual HTML inputs but the bottom 2 are grabbed from my database.

my question is this:

**both the 2 types have the same "li" and "ul" tags. So why do they not look the same?**

thank you.

**EDIT**

the value for the bottom 2 is:

```
   <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

    <ul class="pageitem"><li class="button">
    <a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;"/>
    </li></ul>
              </a> <?php } ?>
```

but it needs to remove the underline.

Comment: Well, the top three links are actually `<input>` submit-buttons, and the bottom two are actual `<a>` links. Can you change the PHP for the bottom two links to match the form of the `<input>`s?

Comment: have a look at the origional post I have edited my code. and take another look at my site.

Comment: There's still a difference between the HTML for the top three links and for the bottom two. If you look at the source of the generated HTML page, it might be easier to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted this.

please look at my link again.

the code I used is this.

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>

<style>
a:link, a:visited, a:hover{color:black; text-decoration:none;}
</style>


<ul class="pageitem"><li class="button">   
<a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>"/>
</li></ul>
          </a> <?php } ?>
```

please one up this.

Thank you.

Comment: not very [well-formed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element), and you don't have to style every iteration

Comment: ok. i have removed ", a:visited, a:hover" this is ok. does it matter that it is not correctly formated if it works?

Comment: @kevstarlive in my opinion it does not really matter

Comment: it only works because your browser is correcting it for you. what about visitors with older, lightweight or more obscure browsers? what if someone inherits your code and can't understand it? what about coding standards, legibility, maintainability and SEO?

Comment: verbumSapienti as my site is MOBILE (hense .mobi) and the fact that all the latest mobile browsers have the latest updates. im sure I will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not formatted correctly

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
    <ul class="pageitem">
        <li class="button" style="text-align:center;font-weight: bold;">
        <a href="list.php?id=<?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>">
        <?php echo $article['promo_cat']; ?>
        </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this does not work. the way I did it in my post looks better.

Comment: please take another look

Comment: Put the loop wthin the `<ul></ul>` tags